# MvvmCross: Tips for mixing MvvmCross with normal techniques

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

I am trying to convert a mid-size application to use MvvmCross that is already developed using Xamarin for both iOS and Android, but using normal techniques.  Is it possible to mix MvvmCross techniques with normal style viewcontrollers and activities such that I can take my time slowing migrating screen by screen over to MvvmCross?  At my current rate, it might take me a few weeks to convert the entire app over to MvvmCross and I would prefer it not to be an all or nothing procedure.  My boss may not be willing to wait until I am completely finished so having some of it done before I switch over to working on enhancements would help later when I get more time to finish the conversion.  Therefore, any tips you can think of for a slow migration screen by screen to MvvmCross would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to mix MvvmCross techniques with normal style viewcontrollers and activities such that I can take my time slowing migrating screen by screen over to MvvmCross?

Yes, you can easily mix and match 'code-behind' with MvvmCross.

For example, see projects like https://github.com/slodge/eh which uses a Storyboard with MvvmCross data-binding.

> Therefore, any tips you can think of for a slow migration screen by screen to MvvmCross would be helpful.

Sorry - I don't personally think this second half is a good format of question for StackOverflow - it's just too general and non-specific. Maybe better to come back and ask specific individual questions when you hit specific issues or where you have specific problems with individual viewcontrollers.

Comment: For example, on Android when trying to navigate from a regular Activity to an MvvmCross ViewModel, I just simply tried to start the ViewModel activity directly.  I received an MvvmCross error:

"Null Extras seen on Intent when creating ViewModel - this should not happen - have you tried to navigate to an MvvmCross View directly?"

These are the kinds of tips I am looking for.  How to navigate from regular view to Mvvm view and how to navigate from Mvvm view to regular view for both iOS and Android?

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the sort of question I meant when I said: "Maybe better to come back and ask specific individual questions when you hit specific issues". I know how to answer specific questions. Anyway, over and out from me on this - if others have hints or tips then hopefully they can leave them here for you - but personally I think that's a 'long shot'. Stuart